# Make generic object optional when mapping over object keys (in keyof)

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, option-type, keyof

I have problem with mapping in `keyof`. I'm trying to map over `Routes` type, but when I map over the object then it breaks conditional params for `Route`.

```ts
type Routes = {
    '/home': {}
    '/pages': {
        pageId: number
    }
}

type IRoute<RouteName, Params> = {
    route: RouteName
} & ({} extends Params ? { params?: Params } : { params: Params })

type Router = {
    [RouteName in keyof Routes]: IRoute<RouteName, Routes[RouteName]>
}

type Route = Router[keyof Router]
```

Here `params` should be required but TS ignores it:

```ts
const foo: Route = {
    route: '/pages'
    // Missing params: { pageId: number }
}
```

I need `Route` type with `routeName` and `params`. If `params` is a generic object then make it optional.

```ts
const foo3: IRoute<'/foo', {id: number}> = {
    route: '/foo',
    params: {
        id: 1
    }
}

const foo4: IRoute<'/foo', {}> = {
    route: '/foo'
}
```

Here's my code. If you call `IRoute` it works as I expect. But when `IRoute` is called from mapping through in `keyof` it breaks and `params` is optional for all routes.

Here's a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Routes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'%2Fhome'%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'%2Fpages'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pageId%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20IRoute%3CRouteName%2C%20Params%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20RouteName%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20(%7B%7D%20extends%20Params%20%3F%20%7B%20params%3F%3A%20Params%20%7D%20%3A%20%7B%20params%3A%20Params%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Router%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BRouteName%20in%20keyof%20Routes%5D%3A%20IRoute%3CRouteName%2C%20Routes%5BRouteName%5D%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Route%20%3D%20Router%5Bkeyof%20Router%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%3A%20Route%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Fhome'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo2%3A%20Route%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Fpages'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Missing%20params%3A%20%7B%20pageId%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo3%3A%20IRoute%3C'%2Ffoo'%2C%20%7Bid%3A%20number%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Ffoo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo4%3A%20IRoute%3C'%2Ffoo'%2C%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Ffoo'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo5%3A%20IRoute%3C'%2Ffoo'%2C%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Ffoo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition from:

```
{} extends Params ?
```

to:

```
keyof Params extends never ?
```

See the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Routes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'%2Fhome'%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'%2Fpages'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pageId%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20IRoute%3CRouteName%2C%20Params%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20RouteName%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20(keyof%20Params%20extends%20never%20%3F%20%7B%20params%3F%3A%20Params%20%7D%20%3A%20%7B%20params%3A%20Params%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Router%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BRouteName%20in%20keyof%20Routes%5D%3A%20IRoute%3CRouteName%2C%20Routes%5BRouteName%5D%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Route%20%3D%20Router%5Bkeyof%20Router%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%3A%20Route%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Fhome'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo2%3A%20Route%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Fpages'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Missing%20params%3A%20%7B%20pageId%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo3%3A%20IRoute%3C'%2Ffoo'%2C%20%7Bid%3A%20number%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Ffoo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo4%3A%20IRoute%3C'%2Ffoo'%2C%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Ffoo'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo5%3A%20IRoute%3C'%2Ffoo'%2C%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3A%20'%2Ffoo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: I agree this solution work, but I am unsure why `{} extends Params ?` does not. This seems to work outside the mapped type but not inside it.